# assigning values to the variables

Tags: java, inheritance, annotations, polymorphism, abstract-class

hello in my projework and almost finished everything bu ran into a sm it so any help will be appreciated.
It class and in my classes i cannot access the variables for some reasons and they are not printing
sabcdahwidawidaowidawiodhwaidadihqwdoihqwdoihodihwdiohqwdoihqwdioqwddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
i am having troubles in my project?
how i can fix this??
can someone please help????

```
import java.util.
public abs
public String fi
pub
public 
Per

}
public voo() {  
    System.out.printlmber);
}   
}





public vo
}




import java.util.Scanner;
public cl
public double gpa;
StuScanner(System.in);
    System.out
    programNam
    System.out.printer: ");
    st
    System.out.print("Enter first name: ");
    firstName = sc.next();
    System.out.print("Enter last name: ");
    las
    System.out.print("Enter: ");
    ema
    System.out.print("Enter phone number: ");
    phoneN
   {
    Scanner sc =m.in);
    Sys("Enrses: ");

    doubl
    for(i
        System.out.print(""":");
        ma
    }

    ca  
   }
   @Override
    public void calculateGPA(double
    for(int i=0; i < m
 
   publiInfo() {
    System.out.printf("%25d  
,programName ;
}
 }




import jr;
publ
doub
    System.out.
}

public void printInfo() {   
    super.pr
    System.out.printf("%25d |\n"    
}
}




import java.util.Scanner;
public class Par    
d
ParttimeStud
@Override
public void rea
    Scanner sc = new 
    System.out.println("Ent cous:");
    courseFeesTotal
    System.out.prir credit hours:");
    cid printInfo() {   
    super.printInfo
import java.uti
public class College {
St
S
College
public void pri
    System.out.print
    fo
);
    System.out.printf("%n%15s  | %15s  | %15s  | %15s  | %15s  | %15s  | %15s  | %15s  |\n"
 "Programr
}
public void ReadStudls() {
    Scanner sc =ystem.in)
    System.out.printlnStud");
    System.out.print");
    int type = sc);
    if (type == 1) {    
        FulltimeStudent ftewdent();
        fts.readInfo();
    }
    else
        ParttimeSs = new nt(
    }
    else if (type 2) { 
nter ***");
    }
    while (type <1 || type >2){
        System.out.prinime S
        System.out.print("En

        }
        else}
        else if (type <1 || type >2) { 
public void printStude{
    if (
        System");
    }
    else {
        printTitle();
        for (intnts {
            if (stud 
                si]();
        }
    
}
}




import java.util.Scanner;
 public class ColltemTest {
public static voing[] args) {   
    Scanner sc = new Sc
    System.out.prine
    String name = s
    System.out.prin
    int ;   
    College c = newudents);     
    
    do {
        System.out.printent \n2 os \
  \
        option = 
            c.ReadStudentDeta
        else if 
    }while(optihilewning 
  until option 3 is cho
}
```

Comment: You should format your question properly

Comment: my question how i can print the info because right now my program is assigning null values to the variables however I'm inputting values to them and in the college class when i call the print method its not outputting anything except the title so if you run the program you will understand what i mean hopefully this explanation helps

Comment: The purpose of formatting is to make it easier for other people to read your code.  If you **want** people to help you, then it is in your own interest to do that.

Comment: As far as I can see, you never assign anything to the `students` array.

Comment: @StephenC how can i format it

Comment: @tgdavies where? i think i assigned marks and numStudents to it

Comment: There is help on formatting in the EDIT view.  Also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: I don't think you did either.  The array is allocated, but nothing assigns anything to an array cell of `students`.  It looks like the objects in `fts` and `pts` just get thrown away ...

Comment: @StephenC i tried making my question better i did some spacing between the classes. And how do you think i should assign anything to the array cell of students I'm trying to fix it but still I'm not getting the desired results.

Comment: @StephenC And for the objects fts and pts I think they are working in that part. I think the problems are in the print methods in the college and student classes.

Comment: "And how do you think i should assign anything to the array cell of students I'm trying to fix it but still I'm not getting the desired results." - You should assign the `fts` and `pts` to cells in the array.   The problem is NOT in the print methods.

Comment: @StephenC can you tell me how I can do that I'm not understanding what you mean.

Comment: @StephenC the array type is int and the fts and pts types is as their classes FullltimeStudent and PartTimeStudent

Answer (score 1):

Lets work this through, starting with the `printStudentDetails()`

You say that nothing is being output (presumably ... other than the title).

```
    for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++) {
        if (students[i] != null) 
            students[i].printInfo();
    }
```

Q: Why would that print nothing?

A: Two possible reasons:

1. Because `numStudents` is zero.
2. Because `students[i]` is `null` ... for all `i`.

So lets take a look at the code above:

```
Student [] students;
int numStudents;
College(){}

College(String name, int num) {
    this.name = name;
    students = new Student[num];
}
```

In English, when a `College` is created, `student` is initialized to an array of `Student` objects whose length will be `num`.  The elements of that array will all be `null`.  The value `numStudents` will be zero.

(Is this ringing any bells yet?)

So lets then look at `ReadStudentDetails` code where the student information is read.

```
int type = sc.nextInt();
if (type == 1) {    
    FulltimeStudent fts = new FulltimeStudent();
    fts.readInfo();
}
...
```

Q: What happens to the `FulltimeStudent` object?

A: You read information into it, and then .... nothing.  The `fts` variable goes out of scope and nothing will be able to see / use the object you just created.

Q: How does it get into the `student` array?

A: It doesn't!!

Q: Why is `numStudents` **still** zero<sup>1</sup>?  Why is `students` still all `nulls`?

A: Because your code hasn't changed either of them ... when it created the `Student` object!!  Or anywhere else.

Q: So what **should** it do?

A: It should:

1. Check that `numStudents` is less than `students.length`.
2. Assign the reference in `fts` to `students[numStudents]`.
3. Increment `numStudents` by one.

Reading through the rest of the method there are 3 other places where you are doing the same thing ... more or less.  Similar correcions are required in each case.

<sup>1 - In fact, I noticed that *right at the end* of the `ReadStudentDetails` method you are incrementing `numStudents` ... ONCE.  So the variable will be one rather than zero.  But you didn't put any of the students into `students`, so there won't be anything there to print.</sup>

---

### The Lessons to Learn

The main lesson here is that an application does what you (the programmer) tell it to do (in the code).  Nothing more.  Nothing less.  If you don't tell it to assign something ... it won't.

So if you want to figure out why your application is not working, you need to carefully read what you told it to do in code.  **Carefully**.  Then compare what you are seeing (e.g. output, exceptions ... or no output) with the code.  And apply some reasoning to the problem.

> I saw behavior X.  What are the circumstances that could give rise to that behavior?  What can I deduce about the state of the program?  Can I confirm that some other way?  (By adding trace print statements to print out variables.  By using my IDE's debugger.  By looking at other evidence.)

Then work backwards ... to figure out how / why the circumstances or state that you can observe or hypothesize *could* have happened ... until you reach the point where you have identified the flaw (bug) in your code.

I recommend that you take the time to read these:

- [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
- [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/)

---

I will also note that there are other bugs in your code ... but I'm not going to point them out.  Also, there a lot of style errors in the code as you have written it.  I don't know if you assignment will be marked on coding style, but if it is you should (IMO) lose most of the style marks.  Make sure that you fix them before you submit the assignment.  (And I'm not going to point them out.  Check your lecture notes, etcetera.)